# How do downgrade Maven version from 3.2.X to 3.0.4

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I need to dowgrade all my maven settings in eclipse, as the higher version is not supporting some dependencies and even in some eclipse ide's it's being difficult to download maven integration.

Comment: What kind of dependencies?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the version you want to use in you `pom.xml` file

```
<properties>
  <maven.version>3.0.4</maven.version>
</properties>
```

and define the dependencies with such property within your pom file.

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
    <version>${maven.version}</version>
  </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

In eclipse go to: **Window > Preferences > Maven > Installations** and then select the maven version from the installations list. Add the installation if it isn't yet in the list.